# While loop not working well

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

Hi I have this code for selecting items from a python list. The problem is that once it loops over

CODE:

```
import re
name = input
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your search term here:").lower()
    def FindName(name,list1):
        """ searches for a pattern in the list, returns the complete list entry. Is case       sensitive.
May return incomplete value if ' is in the list value (ie confucius's)"""
    if name in list1:
        return name
    else:
        string1 = str(list1).replace('"',"'")
        pattern = re.compile("[']"+name+"[^']*")
        match = re.search(pattern,string1)
        if match:
            if match.group().lstrip("'") in list1:
                return match.group().lstrip("'")
            else:
                print 'Fail %s' %match.group().lstrip("'")
                return None
        else:
            return ' '.join(name2) 
    china=['In', 'China', 'people', 'teach',"Confusius's",
    'teachings','dilligently.','Those',"Confusius''s",
    'teachings','are','called','Taoism.']
    india=['India', 'bopal', 'mahindra', 'gujarat',"gandhi's",
    'bombay',"Gandhi",]        ]

    name2 = name[:]
    this= ' '.join(name2)
    print FindName(this,china)
    for item in china:            
        print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(china) if x.startswith(this)]
    this = ' '.join(name2)
    for item in india:
        print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(india) if x.startswith(this)]
    this = ' '.join(name2)
    for item in india:
        print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(india) if x.endswith(this)]
    this = ' '.join(name2)
    for item in india:
        print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(china) if x.startswith(this)]
     loop continues......
```

The problem is that I have tried to put break on the loop but it still prints: `print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate...` on every loop as it goes down the loop. How can I make it loop over the statements but only prints intended items without looping and printing `print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(china) if x.startswith(this)]` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have doubled-up your printing for each result. Instead of this:

```
for item in china:            
    print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(china) if x.startswith(this)]  # will print relevant index and item of china once for every item in china
```

try this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(china):
    if item.startswith(this):
        print (index, item)  # will print each relevant index and item in china only once
```

or this:

```
print [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(china) if x.startswith(this)]  # no for-loop
```

for each for-loop. If you want to break out of the larger while-loop, you will need to insert a `break` **outside of** the for-loops:

```
while True:
    ...
    if <something>:
        break
    for ...
```